# Javascript width and height return 0 even while loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've been messing around with galleries. Specifically using javascript to change the width and the height when the picture is clicked on. As you can see in the documents below I tried using measurements from the clients browser size to get the correct width, and then getting a ratio from the picture to assign a height. The only problem is that when I try to get the height and width of the image the functions only return 0. I've done a bit of research and found that the images have to be loaded to be measured. Having it specifically load hasn't worked. I have tried quite a few variations of the below code but nothing seems to work. I was hoping someone could point out the obvious error that i'm missing.

Thank you in advance.
The HTML, CSS, and JS documents are below. 
This occurs in the most recent versions of chrome, firefox, and internet explorer.

HTML Document:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Avacados</title>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body onLoad="resizeAll();">
        <img id="img1" src="assets/2.jpg" onClick="resize(1);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img2" src="assets/3.jpg" onClick="resize(2);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img3" src="assets/4.jpg" onClick="resize(3);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img4" src="assets/6.jpg" onClick="resize(4);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img5" src="assets/7.jpg" onClick="resize(5);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img6" src="assets/8.jpg" onClick="resize(6);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img7" src="assets/2.jpg" onClick="resize(7);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img8" src="assets/3.jpg" onClick="resize(8);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img9" src="assets/4.jpg" onClick="resize(9);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img10" src="assets/6.jpg" onClick="resize(10);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img11" src="assets/7.jpg" onClick="resize(11);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img12" src="assets/8.jpg" onClick="resize(12);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img13" src="assets/2.jpg" onClick="resize(13);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img14" src="assets/3.jpg" onClick="resize(14);" alt="avacado"/>
        <img id="img15" src="assets/4.jpg" onClick="resize(15);" alt="avacado"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="imgresize.js">
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Document:

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;    
}
img {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;    
}
```

JS Document:

```
var flag;
flag = true;
function resize(num) {
    if(flag) { //not clicked
        resizeAll();
        flag = false;
    }
    else { //clicked
            resizeAll();
            setMost(num);
            flag = true;

            //document.getElementById("img" + num).style.width = "auto";
            //document.getElementById("img" + num).style.height = "auto";

            var image = document.getElementById("img" + num); 

            var he2 = document.getElementById("img" + num).height;
            var wi2 = document.getElementById("img" + num).width;
            var ratio = (he2/wi2);

            document.write(he2);
            document.write(wi2);
            //document.write(ratio);

            document.getElementById("img" + num).style.border = "45px solid #ffff00";
            document.getElementById("img" + num).style.padding = "0px";
            document.getElementById("img" + num).style.position = "relative";

            //document.getElementById("img" + num).style.width = "600px";
            //document.getElementById("img" + num).style.height = "400px";

            var he = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 110;
            var wi = document.documentElement.clientWidth - 110;

            document.getElementById("img" + num).style.width = wi + "px";
            document.getElementById("img" + num).style.height = (he*ratio) + "px";

            //var pic = document.getElementById("img" + num).width();
            //var bodysize = document.getElementsById("images").width();
            //var total = (bodysize * .5) - (pic * .5);
            //var pixels = "px";
            //document.getElementById("img" + num).style.left = (bodysize).toString()+"px";
            //document.getElementById("img" + num).style.left = "50%";
            flag = true;
        }
    }
function resizeAll() {
    for (var i=1;i<16;i++) {
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.width = "300px";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.height = "200px";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.border = "0px solid #ffff00";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.padding = "0px";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.position= "relative";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.left = "0%";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.right= "0%";
    }
}
function setMost(num) {
    for (var i=1;i<16;i++) {
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.position= "absolute";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.width = "0px";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.height = "0px";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.border = "0px solid #ffff00";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.padding = "0px";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.left = "0%";
        document.getElementById("img" + i).style.right= "0%";
    }
}
```

Comment: width and height are style attributes. Use `.style.width` and `.style.height`. I see that you did below, but in your call to print the height and width, you didn't... :)

Comment: Also I see in your commented out code, you have `.width()` in there too. Remember that `.width()` and `.height()` are jQuery specific and have to be called with the `$()` around the object. Just put your whole call to the `document.getElementById()` inside the jQuery container: `$(document.getElementById(...)).width()` is a proper statement.